# ld: library not found for -lGoogle-Maps-iOS-Utils

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, linker

I have just received a rather large iOS Xcode Objective-C project from a friend and am currently trying to build and run the solution that was given to me on my own machine.  When I go to run the code, I am given this error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/huxdr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Presence-fwasplradhrerkdlyqnnnacvggws/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
ld: library not found for -lGoogle-Maps-iOS-Utils
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anyone know what I should be adding/including in order for the project to successfully link this library?

Comment: Make sure you have added the Google Maps library to your project and that  it is attached to your target.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials/sites that show the right way to do this?  ive tried a few different ways but still cant get that method to work.

Comment: In your project general tab, add the library to `linked framework and libraries`, it should work

Comment: Might be a little out dated, but should still get the gist of it... https://www.chilkatsoft.com/xcode-link-static-lib.asp Also, here is the Xcode docs http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/